# TClientDataset - XML mapping

Tags: xml, delphi, delphi-2009, tclientdataset

I'm trying to save data in a TClientDataSet to an XML file, but it doesn't like some of my fields.  The helpfile says to create a definition, in one of two ways: either with the xmlmapper.exe file in my \bin folder or with an IDOMDocument interface.

Problem is, xmlmapper.exe isn't there, and IDOMDocument is one of those annoying structures that Delphi 2009 was released without writing up documentation for.  So I have to choose between a non-existent EXE or an interface with no documentation and no indication of which objects implement it or how to create them.

Does anyone know what I'm supposed to do in this case?

Comment: What edition of Delphi do you have?

Comment: Can't you just access the ClientDataSet.XMLData property and save that to a text file?

Answer (score 3):

If you are using fields that are unsupported in delphi's XML serialisation, you need to create your own functions for XML loading/saving.

It's not hard, and if you do it, that code can be expanded for other serialisation formats (JSON, CSV, XLSX, ...).

Comment: I'm sure it's not all that hard.  I just don't know where to go about creating them.

Answer (score 0):

XMLMapper.exe **is** in my \bin directory, it is also under my tools menu (although I may have added it there. . . .)  What edition of Delphi do you have?  I looked at the [feature matrix](http://www.codegear.com/article/38548/images/38548/Delphi2009FeatureMatrix.pdf) and I don't see anything that looks like it that isn't in *all three editions*.  You might run your installation again and see if maybe you skipped the installation of it.

Comment: Just checked.  Only thing I skipped was the ribbon controls.

Comment: It is missing in my (Delphi 2009 Professional) bin directory too. AFAIK it is for XML Data Binding, which is included in the Enterprise/Architect editions only.

Answer (score 0):

You might look at some 3rd party Delphi books (Marco Cantu has a few) and see if they document IDOMDocument.  You also might [look around for some examples](http://www.google.com/search?q=Delphi+example+of+IDOMDocument).

Answer (score 0):

A third option is to simply iterate over all records and write the fields to XML with self-written code, using a XML library like OmniXML or NativeXml.

This has the advantage to have total control over the conversion of all field types and specific fields.

Answer (score -1):

Declaration:

```
void __fastcall SaveToFile(const System::UnicodeString FileName = System::UnicodeString(), TDataPacketFormat Format = (TDataPacketFormat)(0x0));
Mem1->SaveToFile("C:\wateverfile.xml",dfXMLUTF8);
```

or

```
Mem1->SaveToFile("C:\wateverfile.xml",dfXML);
```

or

```
Mem1->SaveToFile("C:\wateverfile.cds",dfBinary); //for a binary save
```

- `dfBinary`: Information is encoded in binary format.
- `dfXML`: Information is encoded in XML, with extended characters encoded using an escape sequence.
- `dfXMLUTF8`: Information is encoded in XML, with extended characters represented using UTF8.